# Docker giving IP address at the same level as the host, similar to VM bridged networking

Tags: networking, docker

I want to assign IP addresses to my docker containers, at the same level as the physical host. i.e. if the IP adress of the host is 192.168.1.101 I would like to give the docker containers IP addresses of 192.168.1.102,103,104 etc.

Essentially I am looking for a functionality similar to bridged networking in VMWare/Virtualbox etc.

Any ideas how we can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker's default bridge network allows you to NAT your containers into the physical network.

To achieve what you want, use [Pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) or, if you are cutting edge, you can try the [docker macvlan driver](http://hicu.be/docker-networking-macvlan-bridge-mode-configuration) which is, for now, experimental.

Answer (score 0):

To quote [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/):

> The host network adds a container on the hosts network stack. You’ll
>   find the network configuration inside the container is identical to
>   the host.

When starting the container just say `--net=host`. Check [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings). You can't actually assign a static IP when starting with that parameter, but you can give the container a hostname with `--hostname`, which is at the very least equally useful as knowing the IP. Also you can add more entries to /etc/hosts with `--add-host`.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. The --net=host makes all the networks visible in the host also visible in the container. The host and the container can then share the same IP address. What I would like is to install a linux bridge in the host machine, and then give one of the ip addresses through those bridges to the container. However, I do not know the step-by step process for this.